Ubuntu 22.04 Freezes with Yellow Parallel Lines on Screen -AMD Radeon RX 570
I’m encountering a frustrating issue with my Ubuntu 22.04 setup. After using the system for a while, the screen freezes, and yellow parallel lines appear starting from the right corner of the screen. When this happens, the system becomes completely unresponsive, and I need to hard reboot it.
Here are the details of my setup:
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 570
Ubuntu version: 22.04 LTS
AMD driver: Using the official AMDGPU-Pro drivers (also tried the open-source AMDGPU drivers, but the issue persists)



If this problem also occurs on Windows or when using a live USB, the AMD Radeon RX 570 graphics card is old and may need to be replaced.
